# двунапрвленный список, начало и конец

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct p {
    int data;
    struct p *next;
    struct p *prev;
} list;

list* init(int a);
list* insert_before(list* pc, int num);
list* start(list* pc);
list* end(list* pc);
void print(list* pc);

int main() {
    list *s, *e;
    int a, n;
    printf("Input root value of list: ");
    scanf(" %d", &a);
    list *head = init(a);
    printf("Input quantity values to insert them before root: ");
    scanf(" %d", &n);
    int *values = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf(" %d", &values[i]);
        insert_before(head, values[i]);
    }
    s = start(head);
    e = end(head);
    print(head);
    printf("\n\nStart address of list: %p\nEnd address of list: %p\n\nstart %d\nend %d", s, e, *s, *e);
    return 0;
}

list* init(int a) {
    list* root;
    root = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    root->data = a;
    root->next = NULL;
    root->prev = NULL;
    return root;
}

list* insert_before(list* pc, int num) {
    list* res, *p;
    res = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    p = pc->prev;
    pc->prev = res;
    res->data = num;
    res->prev = p;
    res->next = pc;
    if (p != NULL) p->next = res;
    return res;
}

list* start(list* pc) {
    while (pc->prev != NULL) {
        pc = pc->prev;
    }
    return pc;
}

list* end(list* pc) {
    while (pc->next != NULL) {
        pc = pc->next;
    }
    return pc;
}

void print(list* pc) {
    int i = 0;
    list* p;
    p = pc;
    do {
        printf("%d\n", p->data);
        p = p->prev;
    } while (p != NULL);
    return;
}
```

вот написал рабочий код по двунаправленным спискам. решил протестить адреса начала и конца списка. и проверить это же по значениям. начало списка считается абсолютно правильно, а вот конец.... не знаю правильный ли адрес, но значение... оно даже не похоже на адрес (в printf проверил, чтоб выводились именно значения). что не так? подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: я нашел причину этого. аргумент а почему-то обнуляется к концу главной функции. а вот причины этого я не понимаю(

Comment: проверил всю функцию, где обнуляется эта переменная. ОНА НИГДЕ НЕ ОБНУЛЯЕТСЯ (только на выводе)! это как вообще???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитал предупреждения , переписал:

```
printf("\n\nStart address of list: %p\nEnd address of list: %p\n\nstart %d\nend %d",
 s, e, (*s).data, (*e).data);
```

Правильно ? посмотрите:

```
> ./a.out 
Input root value of list: 7
Input quantity values to insert them before root: 2
1
2
7
2
1


Start address of list: 0x25bc050
End address of list: 0x25bc010

start 1
end 7
```

Comment: ухх, а как раз самое главное и самое банальное я и забыл( то что я работаю со структурами
спасибо большое за то что напомнили! я выводил всю структуру вместо одного значения



.  но все-таки интересно почему обнуляется переменная а... она же не структура, и нигде не используется, кроме инициализации списка... у вас нет идей насчет причины этого?